# Get class instance where a certain property has a certain value

Tags: python, class

I'm sure there is a term for what I'm looking for, or if there's not, there is a very good reason what I'm trying to do is in fact silly.

But anyway. I'm wondering whether there is a (quasi) built-in way of finding a certain class instance that has a property set to a certain value.

An example:

```
class Klass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def square_value(self):
        return self.value * self.value

 >>> a = Klass(1)
 >>> b = Klass(2)
 >>> instance = find_instance([a, b], value=1)
 >>> instance.square_value()
 1
 >>> instance = find_instance([a, b], value=2)
 >>> instance.square_value()
 4
```

I know that I could write a function that loops through all Klass instances, and returns the ones with the requested values. On the other hand, this functionality feels as if it should exist within Python already, and if it's not, that there must be a very good reasons why it's not. In other words, that what I'm trying to do here can be done in a much better way.

(And of course, I'm not looking for a way to square a value. The above is just an example of the construct I'm trying to look for).

Comment: This is very vague. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve? Maybe add some code?

Comment: Sorry - I pushed <enter> in the tags field and submitted the question too early.

Comment: What do you want it to do if there are multiple instances that match? I.e. what should instance be in `instance = find_instance([a, b, a], value=1)`? And what if there are no matches?

Comment: Good question, and the answer is that the return values should be either an instance, a list of instances or None. (A one-item list, a list of instance or an empty list will do fine too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use filter:

```
filter(lambda obj: obj.value == 1, [a, b])
```

Filter will return a list of objects which meet the requirement you specify. Docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter

Bascially, `filter(fn, list)` iterates over `list`, and applies `fn` to each item. It collects all of the items for which `fn` returns true, puts then into a list, and returns them.

NB: filter will always return *a list*, even if there is only one object which matches. So if you only wanted to return the *first* instance which matches, you'd have to to something like:

```
def find_instance(fn, objs):
    all_matches = filter(fn, objs)
    if len(all_matches) == 0:
        return False # no matches
    else:
        return all_matches[0]
```

or, better yet,

```
def find_instance(fn, objs):
    all_matches = filter(fn, objs)
    return len(all_matches) > 0 and all_matches[0] # uses the fact that 'and' returns its second argument if its first argument evaluates to True.
```

Then, you would call this function like this:

```
instance = find_instance(lambda x: x.value == 1, [a, b])
```

and then `instance` would be `a`.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient version of Ord's answer, if you are looking for just one matching instance, would be

```
def find_instance(fn, objs):
    all_matches = (o for o in objs if fn(objs))
    return next(all_matches, None)

instance = find_instance(lambda x: x.value == 1, [a, b])
```

This will stop the search as soon as you find the first match (good if your test function is expensive or your list is large), or `None` if there aren't any matches.

Note that the `next` function is new in Python 2.6; in an older version, I think you have to do

```
try:
   return all_matches.next()
except StopIteration:
   return None
```

Of course, if you're just doing this once, you could do it as a one-liner:

```
instance = next((o for o in [a, b] if o.value == 1), None)
```

The latter has the advantage of not doing a bunch of function calls and so might be slightly faster, though the difference will probably be trivial.

Comment: Dougal's code is an example of a generator expression (note how he enclosed the `o for o in ...` bit with () instead of []. This doesn't pre-build the list of matches, it just creates instructions for *how* to build the list. When you say `next(matches, None)`, Python starts executing the instructions, but it stops when it generates the first match. (You could get more matches by repeatedly calling next()). The `None` bit basically tells the generator to return None if there aren't any matches. Docs for generator expressions: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions